# modules whose every submodule is a homomorphic image

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, modules, localization

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity. Let us say that an $R$-module $M$ satisfies property $\mathcal P$ if every submodule of $M$ is a homomorphic image of $M$.

Can we characterize all Noetherian rings $R$ such that for every $R$-module $M$,  the $R$-module $\prod_{\mathfrak p \in Spec (R)} M_{\mathfrak p}$  satisfies property $\mathcal P$ ?

Comment: By Mohan's remark, every prime ideal has to be maximal (i.e. Krull dimension is zero). In addition $R$ has to be a principal ideal ring. The property passes to finite product so we can suppose $R$ connected (hence local artinian). A few non-reduced examples exist; I'm not sure whether it's the same as artinian local PIR.

Answer (score 1):

I expect that such rings are rare. If $R$ is a domain, then it must be a field. To see this, take $M=K$, the fraction field. Then $M_P=K$ for all primes $P$. But $R\subset \prod M_P$ and there are no non-zero maps from $\prod M_P\to R$ unless $R=K$.